# How to batch remove trash label

Tags: gmail

By accident I got a lot of emails moved to the Trash folder. There I can see them with the "Trash" label, as well as the original label. But it seems impossible to select all mails in trash with a certain label, and then move them anywhere.

Is there any way to just remove the "Trash" label from all emails, so they will only appear in their original labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search for all mails in trash that have a certain label like this:

```
in:trash label:your_custom_label
```

Once you search for them, click on the select box and select *All*. Then, click on the **Move to Inbox** button to get them out of Trash. To move them to their label (i.e. remove them from inbox), from inbox, search for the respective mails and archive them.